# initialize DateTime PhP with d-m-Y instead of m-d-Y

Tags: php, date, datetime

The following code works :

```
$d1 = new DateTime("12/31/2015");
```

which corresponds to the 31th of December 2015.

I take out some date from a database, with the following format : `day`/`month`/`year`. So for example, I get :

```
31/12/2015 - 31th December 2015
02/06/2015 - 2nd June 2015
29/03/2015 - 29 March 2015
....
```

The following code didn't work :

```
$d2 = new DateTime("31/12/2015");
```

The nature of my data are : `string`, and I would like to get the timestamp (this is my final goal but not the matter in this case) for each of these dates.

**Question** : Can we initialize DateTime with **day-month**-year order instead of **month-day**-year ?

**Requirement** : Use of `DateTime` object only (older object are not allowed like `date()`).

Comment: [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or be correct about the [difference between `/` and `-` as a date separator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: ... it *is* nice to see someone not just using the `date()` function for a change, however.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you, please feel free to write the following as an answer : `$d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/2015');` + output : `printf("Date : %s", $d2->format("d-m-Y"));`.

Comment: @CD001 :-) My professors told me `DateTime::` is more optimized than `date()` so now I used it untill the next challenger !

Comment: @Zeratops - not more optimised; but more precise and flexible in that it's timezone aware, daylight savings aware, and can work easily with DatePeriod and DateInterval

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your date after:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M/d/Y', '12/31/2015');
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

look at this page, it could help you:

http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php

You can also select your date in french in SQL, for example:

```
select date_format(leChampDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as dateFrance
```

Comment: The format of the date in `'M/d/Y', '12/31/2015` part is not the one I take back from my database. I needed to use the `day` / `month` / `year` format in the initialization, not to change the order of the parts of my date which would require more line of code.

Comment: Then you can do it in mysql, look at my answer.

Comment: based on the doc , it is 'm/d/Y','12/31/2015' , if you use 'M' it means the 3 alphabet representation of months such as Jan, Feb, etc